# Issue with JDK 8 + Netbeans critical error "nullnull"

Tags: java, netbeans

Firstly I install JDK & JRE, it install correctly and works properly, but when I run Net-beans setup which is of 64 bit , after configuring process it shows an error and shows a message as title of Critical and displaying NUll Null message, I'm using window 8 with 64 bit (OS).

**So how I Can come out from this problem?**

Please help me my all friends on this issue........

Comment: Did you install your JDK & JRE for Windows-8 64 bit? Also, what is your RAM size?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed JDK 64bit. during the setup jdk64 you may face with error when setup is trying install JRE, and it's normal, let just finish the setup.

I always have problems with windows too, you may just simply download the OS-independent package from netbeans.org. just extract and use it.

checking package(either zip or exe) hash is recommended, even a bit would mark the whole package incompatible.

You may also set the `jre_home`, `java_home` and `jdk_home` too before netbeans run.